# jQuery AJAX request not being sent

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two variables, `current_min` and `current_max`. I am setting their values but AJAX is not working.

```
var current_min = $('#min').val();
var current_max = $('#max').val();

//alert(current_min+current_max);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "v.php",
    data: "city=" + current_min,
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
        $('#result').html(response);
    }
});
```

I have checked the console and the error showing is this:

```
no element found
no element found
```

Comment: share html pls..is alert showing something?

Comment: The 'no element found' isn't a standard error message and seems unrelated to the code you've shown. Can you please add a more complete sample of your code to the question.

Comment: no alert shows nthng... just getting error in console

Comment: Set here html code and sever side code(php,...)

Answer (score 1):

Correct Way to Send Data With AJAX Is 
`data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }`

So try like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "v.php",
    data: {"city": current_min},
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
        $('#result').html(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: While true, this won't affect the request being sent. The method the OP is using is still valid in that regard

Comment: yea i tryed ths bt nt wrking.. its my full program